# If a sum is finite, can you conclude the same for the following sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, infinity

If we know that $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) < \infty$,

Then can we conclude that $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\times f(x) < \infty$?

The answer is not immediately obvious to me. I think there may be a simple counter example, but I've not been able to think of one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What do you think if $f(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}$ ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was just about to delete the question before you answered. That is finite, but obviously the latter sum is not. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks.